# Executing Capybara commands on debug while using Capybara Webkit?

Tags: capybara-webkit

With Pry (but also with Rubymine), I'm trying to debug a certain point in the code (using `binding.pry`). After calling Capybara's `save_screenshot`, I'm unable to execute any Capybara related commands (all commands die on time-out). This works out of a "debug mode" and in other web-drivers like Poltergeist.

Comment: What else did you change in your setup?  Could you be running into https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ#threads-dont-work-whats-wrong

Comment: @ThomasWalpole - I don't believe I do, as I don't use Mac (I'm experiencing the issue on both Linux and Windows). Also - this problem does not happen elusively on Pry, but also on Rubymine's Debugger (which I believe is basically the `debug-ruby-ide`gem).
I'm able to execute Capybara commands when using `config.default_driver = :poltergiest` and `config.javascript_driver = :webkit`, but it stops working when changing to `config.default_driver = :webkit`. Am I correct to assume based on your reply it suppose to work? if so - perhaps I should open a bug on the Git repo with more details?

Comment: It is supposed to work, however depending on the exact debugger (and versions) being used there have been issues with IO and thread locking - for instance https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/718 and https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/193

Comment: Yes, I have seen those issues when searching for a way around it. Let's leave Rubymine's debugger on the side, as I don't know how it work completely. I'm using the latest Pry version. I'm stopping run-time using `binding.pry`. With `config.default_driver = : poltergiest`, I can `Capybara.find(:xpath, '//')`. With `config.default_driver = :webkit` (also the latest web-kit) I'm getting a timeout error. So I doubt this a pry bug? as Poltergeist works and also run on a different thread? I guess I'll be opening a bug with the information from `debug=true` on the git repo.

Comment: I don't think you can rule out pry completely since it's been an issue in pry before (only with capybara-webkit and not Poltergeist).  It all depends on how pry is interacting with threads, and what thread methods capybara-webkit is calling.  Have you tried `byebug` instead of pry (assuming you're on ruby >= 2) to see if that also has an issue?  And heres an issue of the same thing in pry-byebug https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug/issues/69 so it's probably either in pry or byebug or the combo of the two

Comment: Find the cause of it. see the answer :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a couple of hours today trying to debug it. I think I found the problem - or at least a way around it.

Our web site has a couple of links that open content in another browser window. Since the automation is quite ancient, and in that time Selenium didn't have a decent way to switch window-context, what we do is to `visit` the opened page by URL, and by this keep only a single window open at any given time.

This works, but something strange happens when running this test on "debug mode" (using `binding.pry` for example). Right before we do any actions on that specific page, we take a screen-shot using Capybara's `save_screenshot` method. On debug this results a corrupted image, and any following Capybara methods will fail on time-out. Opening this page using the link, and handling the windows context switching with Capybara's `handle_window` method solves the issue. It's still a mystery why it only happens with Capybara wekit though (as other web-drivers work properly). I'm guessing that perhaps the DOM might be structured differently.